# I need to reset database evey times once 11:59 sunday comes

Tags: php, mysql, database, time

I need to reset database evey times once 11:59 sunday comes i have database in sql and i need to somehow force it to delete all gathering information during the week shortly i need to reset database information every times once it come 11:59pm sunday i was trying to find some solutions but nothing found php will also work

tried to find solution was not able to do so

Comment: Simply use a cron job or use a Mysql scheduled event

Comment: Rather than simply deleting history every week it would it not be reasonable to simply filter your queries by date?

Comment: Please mention what you have tried. Have you looked into corn jobs, a scheduler etc?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is MySql from the tags on your post.  MySql provides a technology for solving this problem.  Check out scheduled events in MySql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html